# How to return value from the function without exiting from the function?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am adding byte arrays from an array list of another array list of bytes. So, basically, I am playing with nested byte arrays. I am able to add the first index of each byte array but I am unable to return it immediately. The function will return the whole byte array when all indexes are added. But, I want to return the sum of each index separately.

```
public static byte[] final_stream(ArrayList<ArrayList<byte[]>> outerstream) {

    ArrayList<byte[]> streams = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    int x = 0;
    while (x < outerstream.size()) {
        streams = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        for (ArrayList<byte[]> bytes : outerstream) {
            streams.add(bytes.remove(0));
        }
        x++;
        return stream_Addr(streams);  // Here I want to return the value

    }
}  // Here it gives error to return byte[]
```

Comment: you can't. once you return a value, the method is finished. your problem is, in case x > outerstream.size(), your method doesn't return a value, yet it has to, since that is dictated by the method signature. µ

Comment: I'm so confused with that code. Why are you iterating over the `outerstream` in both outer `while` loop and then in the `for` loop? What is `stream_Addr()`? In `streams.add(bytes.remove(0));` you're first removing the 0th element and then adding the remaning bytes to the streams - why?

Comment: @Stultuske I support your comment, but for the fun in it I have to point out that you can return a value and stay in the function a bit longer using `try { return ...; } finally { /* executes after the return */ }`. But of course this doesn't have any benefits over storing the return value in a local variable and returning it later.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong on many levels, a quick (probably incomplete) list:

- you violate java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase(), and variable names (unless constants), too. And you only use the "_" for SOME_CONSTANT
- the term "stream" has a very special meaning in Java. A **list** is **not** a stream (but you can create a true java stream from a list by `yourList.stream()`)
- and yes, what you intend to do in that while loop is beyond my creativity to interpret. Honestly: throw that away, and start from scratch.

Regarding your real question: every "exit" path of a non-void method needs to either throw an exception or to *return* something.

Finally: what you intend to do isn't possible like that in Java. A caller calls a method, and that method returns **one** value and then **ends**.

What you *can* do, is something like:

- thread A creates `someList` and passes that to some thread B somehow
- thread B manipulates that list object, and by using appropriate synchronization the other thread can access that data (while B continues to make updates)

And the real answer is: you can't learn a new language by *assuming* that the language supports a concept you know from other languages (like pythons generators) to then *invent* your own syntax or construct in the new language to then be surprised "gosh, it doesn't work". It goes the other way round: you research if your target language has such a concept, if not, you research what else is offered. Then you read a tutorial about that, and follow that.